# Como visualizar en el template de django información de un modelo manytomany

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

Estoy practicando django pero no puedo mostrar la siguiente información de la base de datos en el template.

Tengo estos 3 modelos (ORDENES DE COMPRA, MOVIMIENTOS, COMPROBANTES):

```
class Ordenes_Compra(models.Model):
    orden_compra=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    proveedor=models.ForeignKey(Proveedores, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comedor=models.ForeignKey(Centros, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_documento=models.DateField()
    fecha_entrega=models.DateField()
    class Meta():
        verbose_name='Orden de compra'
        verbose_name_plural="Ordenes de compra"


class Movimientos(models.Model):
    movimientos = [
    ('ING', 'INGRESO'),
    ('SAL', 'SALIDA'),
    ]
    estados = [
    ('PRO', 'PROCESADO'),
    ('ANA', 'ANALIZADO'),
    ('PEN', 'PENDIENTE'),
    ('CAN', 'CANCELADO'),
    ]
    cantidad_um=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=20)
    precio_por_um=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=20)
    mat_um=models.ForeignKey(Materiales, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=True)
    orden_compra_mov=models.ForeignKey(Ordenes_Compra,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipo_movimiento=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=movimientos, blank=True, null=True)
    estado_movimiento=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=estados, blank=True, null=True) 
        
class Imagenes_Comprobantes_Moviemientos (models.Model):
    imagen_factura=models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    factura=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    orden_compra_imagen=models.ManyToManyField(Ordenes_Compra)
    class Meta():
        verbose_name='Comprobante'
        verbose_name_plural="Comprobantes"
```

Cada ORDEN DE COMPRA puede tener varios COMPROBANTES RELACIONADOS y varios COMPROBANTES pueden tener distintas ORDENES DE COMPRA.

En el template, voy a mostrar una tabla con los MOVIMIENTOS, desde el que quiero dar la información de las ORDENES DE COMPRA que están relacionadas a ese movimiento y los COMPROBANTES relacionados a esa ORDENES DE COMPRA:

Pensaba en algo así, pero no funciona y estoy totalmente perdido en como sería la mejor manera de obtener en el template la información de los comprobantes relacionados a la orden de compra relacionado al movimiento.:

**EL SEGUNDO FOR ES EN EL QUE HAGO LA CONSULTA QUE NO ESTARÍA PUDIENDO RESOLVER**

```
    {% for registro in movimientos %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{registro.cantidad_um|floatformat:2}}</td>
            <td>{{registro.orden_compra_mov.orden_compra}}</td>
            <td>{{registro.orden_compra_mov.comedor.nombre_centro}}</td>                  
            <td>
              {% for comprobante in registro.orden_compra_mov.orden_compra %}
                  
                  {{comprobante}}

              {% endfor %}
            </td>
```

Gracias por su ayuda!

(por si es necesario dejo la view)

```
def movimientos(request):

movimientos = Movimientos.objects.annotate(total=F('precio_por_um') * F('cantidad_um'))

return render(request, 'app/movimientos.html', {'movimientos':movimientos})
```

Answer (score 1):

lo pude solucionar, la cuestión era acceder a la relación inversa mediante related_name.

Dejo el link de la documentación:[django documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/)